# git: How to update 'master' branch with a file from the 'dev' branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am quite new to 'git', although I have a moderate amount of experience with 'svn' already, but I have never had the need to make use of branches with either system until now.

I am working on my first (small) collaborative project, and so have made a `dev` branch and have been working on my dev/test changes on the `dev` branch (and have uploaded them to the `dev` branch in the repo). My current version of the code is now ready to become the new `master` version (before then working on the next `dev` revision).

I see that another collaborator has since added a new file (which does not affect the file that I am working on) to the `master` branch (which I was not previously aware of, as I am in the `dev` branch locally).

I now need to update the version of "**myfile**" in the `master` branch with the version of "**myfile**" from the `dev` branch, while not affecting the "**theirfile**" that the other developer added (and, I suppose, also ideally downloading "**theirfile**" to my local copy of the `master` branch as well).

I knew that I would need to deal with this issue in due course, but the presence of this additional file in the `master` branch on the repo perhaps makes things a little more complicated.

As I am still not too familiar with 'git', and, especially, as I don't want to inadvertently mess up our code repo, could someone please advise what I need to do to update the repo accordingly?

Comment: What you want is called "to merge". You want to checkout master (the branch you want to merge into), and then merge with develop (the branch you want to merge from). This will bring all the changes from the develop branch into master so that master also contains those changes. Later, when you're more familiar with git you might want to checkout rebasing but for now I would advice you to stick with merging.

Comment: If you can track the revisions that make up the history of said file, you could cherry-pick them (assuming there are no other files involved on those revisions). The other thing you can try is to "checkout" the file providing the other branch (```git checkout branch --
 <path-to-file>```) and git will "add" it to your index (it will be committed as a new file on your current branch, no relation to the other revisions on the other branch).

Comment: `git pull origin master` - it'll make merge automatically

Comment: `git checkout dev` , copy the file elsewhere, `git checkout master`, paste+replace the file in the desired location. commit when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be merging into your master branch with that file. 
Depending on the git client that you are using you might want to submit a merge request so that the rest of your team can verify this change.

If this is the only file that you have edited, or you are confident that all files in your 'dev' branch are the same as - or updated - versions of their corresponding files in master then use the following command.

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
git add '{your updated files}'
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could I just check that I am hopefully understanding what this does (to help with my understanding of git), before actually trying this?

1. Switch to the `master` branch and download any changes from upstream
2. (Magic happens?)
3. Add the specified files into my copy of `master`
4. Commit those changes locally
5. Commit those changes to the repo.

Is the above a reasonable understanding (and could you perhaps help me to understand the "magic" part)?

Comment: Yeah that's absolutely correct. You might want to always do a git pull when switching branches just in case. I reasonably new to git too, and it seems like the best commands to ensure that you don't make any drastic mistakes are git pull and git push. Every time you want to make a commit, I'd advise pulling (if you are not the only person working on the branch). Once you have made a local commit, push it to the server immediately.